# Chaining unlimited promises

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, chaining

I am trying to do an (expensive) computation from a function which gets called very often and needs to return as quickly as possible. The computation itself doesn't need to be done quickly, it's more important for the computations to occur after each other.

I had the idea of chaining promises together with `this` and the following seems to work, but I am unsure whether this is a bad way of doing it:

```js
let promiseChain = Promise.resolve();
function func() {
  (async () => {
    promiseChain = promiseChain.then(() => {
      doComputation(); // returns nothing
    });
  })();
}
```

(Edit)
Some more details:
The `func` I'm writing looks actually more like this:

```js
function func() { // gets called everytime the DOM changes
  const node = capture(document); // Essentially this clones the DOM
  (async () => {
    promiseChain = promiseChain.then(() => {
      doComputation(node); // returns nothing
    });
  })();
}
```

The reason `func` needs to exit so quickly is that DOM changes may occur in quick succession and I want to capture all changes. This is why I thought exiting `func` quickly by running it's content asynchronously might solve that. The computation itself can be synchronous (and needs to be in order) and I thought chaining them together with `then` would achieve that.

Comment: JS is a single thread language. You cannot make sync calculations on the main thread as async. So your promise chain doesn't make sense in this particular case.

Comment: What are you expecting to occur when you call `func()`? Also, `promiseChain` looks a lot like `Promise.resolve();`...

Comment: @HereticMonkey `promiseChain` is just the instantiation of what will be the canonical chain, with each next call appending a promise after the previous one is resolved.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Thanks for the reply, I added some details to the question.

Comment: If `doComputation()` returns nothing, and the `.then(…)` callback does not return anything either, there is absolutely no point in creating a promise chain for it. Any synchronous computation is automatically "in order".

Comment: @Bergi But it's an asynchronous computation, is it not? It's called from an async context. Is it not possible that >1 `doComputation`s are running at the same time?

Comment: @simeon No, there is no such thing as an "asynchronous context". The computation does not become asynchronous itself just by doing it later (in an asynchronous callback), all callbacks still run synchronously in the same thread.

Comment: @Bergi I firmly believed until now that `async` meant "runs in a new thread". Clearly I should have started reading the reference from the beginning. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JS is a single thread language. You cannot make sync calculations on the main thread as async. So your promise chain doesn't make sense in this particular case. YOu can just use an ordinary sync code, for example loop through your calculation functions executing them.

If you want execute a chain of async tasks you can just loop through them with `async/await`.

If you want to do expensive calculations without blocking the UI use Web workers:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers

A simple solution to execute computations in a worker queued could be like that:

```js
let taskId = 1;

const executeFunctionInWorker = function(fn){

  const id = taskId++;
  
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    const blob = new Blob([`
    let start = performance.now();
    (${fn.toString()})();
    postMessage({duration: performance.now() - start});
    `], {type: 'application/javascript'});
    const worker = new Worker(URL.createObjectURL(blob));
    worker.addEventListener('message', e => {
      resolve(`Finished task ${id} in ${e.data.duration}ms`);
    });
  });
  
};

const doComputation = () => {
  let count = 1000;
  while(count--){
    structuredClone(Array.from({length: 5000}, () => Math.random()));      
  }
};

class PromiseQueue{
  tasks = [];
  async push(task){
    const starting = this.tasks.length === 0;
    this.tasks.push(task);
    if(starting){
      let task;
      while(task = this.tasks[0]){
        const result = await task();
        this.tasks.shift();
        console.log(result);
      }
    }
  }
};

const queue = new PromiseQueue;

const push = () => Array.from({length: 5}, () => queue.push(() => executeFunctionInWorker(doComputation)));
```

```html
<button onclick="push()">Queue 5 tasks</button>
<div>You can press any number you want without waiting the previous tasks to complete</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But doesn't your example require the amount of tasks to be predetermined? I'm also not sure I understand what you mean with `You cannot make sync calculations on the main thread as async`. Doesn't `then` wait for the previous `then` to have completed, effectively making the tasks synchronous, even if they still are async to the main thread (which does not matter in my case)? I'm sorry if I am grossly misunderstanding something.
I also added some details to my question.

Comment: @simeon if your `doComputation()` is sync, using promises doesn't make sense, it does nothing

Comment: But if `doComputation` is called from an async function that gets executed in quick succession wouldn't that mean a `doComputation` call is possible to complete before a previous `doCompuatation` call?

Comment: @simeon added a simple queue class to execute any async function only 1 at a time

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to create such an extensive example, I understand much better now

Comment: @simeon i've removed `executeFunctionInWorker` from `PromiseQueue` so it would handle only pure Promises, moved `executeFunctionInWorker` to the button's click code